# System.Threading.Timer will stop after a few times

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

I have a `System.Threading.Timer` in a VB.NET service. However I am not sure why the timer only runs for 14 times and then stops. The service still keep runnings. Here is the code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim downloadCall As New TimerCallback(AddressOf download_tick)
    Dim timerDownload As New Timer(downloadCall, Nothing, 0, 8000)
End Sub

Private Sub download_tick(ByVal sender As Object) 
   System.IO.File.AppendAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\test\" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".txt", "")
   Dim th As New Thread(AddressOf downloadPrintJob)
   th.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub downloadPrintJob()
Try
    Using webClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    .....
```

From the above code, I found that there are 14 text-files being generated every time if I restart the service.

Comment: Well one thing I see is that you're `Dim`'ing your timer in `OnStart` and then dropping reference to it when `OnStart` finishes. The GC could be swallowing it up, although I didn't think it would be as deterministic as disposing it after 14 ticks every time you run it. Also, what if two downloads finish at the same time and you append them to the same file (if the seconds are the same)?

Comment: Thanks helrich, you are right, I moved the timer declaration outside the onstart and then it works. For the 2 downloads complete at the same time, it does throw an exception "text file is in use by other process".

Comment: Cool! Glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the download takes more than 8 seconds?

I would start by disabling the timer while the job is downloading and then re-enable it when the job is complete.